# Python deobsofucation tzlibtbase64t - base64 with / and +

Tags: python, base64, compression, deobfuscation

I would like to verify that a script its running what it claims. The target script ([tracker.py](https://github.com/ShuBhamg0sain/phone-number-tracker/blob/master/tracker.py)) seems to be obsofucated with [this other script](https://github.com/htr-tech/Pycompile) (also obsofucated) using marshal, zlib, base64, base32 and base16 because its mentioned in the comments of tracker.py.

I've got to a point that the right path definetly seems to decode/decompress with base64 and/or zlib because I'm following the same patterns I used to solve the first base64 deobsofucation   step.

In other words, the following script produces the following output:

#### script.py

---

```
import marshal,base64

# exec(
print(marshal.dumps(base64.b32decode("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")))
```

#### output

---

```
sc@s6ddlZddlZejejddUdS(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(tzlibtbase64t
decompresst     b64decode(((sdg<module>s
```

By following the exact steps I used to deobsofucate the previous layer I'm sure that I have to decompress/decode with zlib/base64 the string between **iNseJw1l...tknLHA==** because **tzlibtbase64t** is next to the output string. Kinda like if its next step would be to run the  function `tzlibtbase64t(iNseJw1l...tknLHA==)`

Obviously I have already tried decompressing it with zlib and decoding it with base64 without success and since I couldn't even get one output right, chaining from one to another wasn't possible. I'm also sure that `string.txt` doesn't end with a newline. I also did a quick google search of the base64 format but I didn't get relevant results.

```
# zlib
openssl zlib -d < string.txt
zlib-flate -uncompress < string.txt

# base64
cat string.txt | base64 -d
```

#### string.txt

```
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
```

[Similar unanswered question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197479/weird-python-script-found-on-a-mac-os-x-client-machine)

## TL;DR

How to decompress/decode `string.txt`?

Comment: Here's a script that will reverse it: https://pastebin.com/LmSyizQz | It's mostly nested [Python code objects](https://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects), so generally looked at its `co_names` and `co_consts` members, and then disassebled its `co_code` (using `dis.dis`). That showed quite clearly the steps done, and allowed me to write a little more of the script to skip the exec. Then rinse and repeat. Shouldn't be too hard to automate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply with sources, it really helped! But the pastebin seems to be private because I'm getting the following when opening it "Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it."

Comment: Yeah. It's set to public, but there's some sort of moderation going on, maybe because it has that big obfuscated string. Did you login and manage to access it, or should I try to make another version without the payload?

Comment: I did and it didn't work. I will be very thankful if you could make the other version without the payload.

Comment: How about this: https://pastebin.com/FAkPVEUB | I can load it in a browser where I'm not logged in, unlike the previous one. | BTW, in hindsight, it would be easier to use `dis.disco` on the code object itself instead of what I did. It shows you the values of the names/consts which saves some manual cross referencing.